# Full IDE features support for golang in Doom Emacs

Tags: go, emacs

I'm a vim user for years and start to play emacs recently, after having tried Spacemacs and Prelude, Doom Emacs is my final choose. I'm configuring golang development those days with (go +lsp) and (lsp) module, and all the out-of-box features of Doom are impressive, thanks for your outstanding job hlissner.

Now I'm happy with the basic features like:

Auto completion

- flycheck
- snippets
- other go-mode features

But to be more productive, I want more IDE-like features such as:

- Navigation: Until now I only found counsel-imenu by which I can select symbols in current buffer(candidates not grouped by method/function/var/const/interface and so on), but how could I do things like:

  - Find symbols in a project
  - Find Interfaces in a project
  - Find Structs in a project
  - Find methods in a project
  - Find exported functions, maybe in a specified package
  - Switch back and force between source code and related test file/method
  - And so on...
- More sophisticated actions to generate/operate code: snippets and go-gen-test are a great help, but is it possible to do the following this:

  - Code actions to generate undeclared method/field/function/package in different scope, now it seems it can only generate variable. (Is this based on the lsp backend support? I found a  video for java but not able to find one for go)
  - Auto-generate methods template if I specify an Interface to implement for a Struct
  - Remove methods from a struct
  - Auto-remove relative test/bench functions if I remove a function/method

Could anybody help me on this? And any experiences/tips are appreciated.

Comment: emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info (Applies to StackOverflow too.)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Welcome aboard!

I'm not a go programmer myself, so these are mostly 2nd hand accounts, but Doom's `:lang go` module provides most of what you're asking for. I would suggest using the `gopls` langserver. To do so:

1. [Enable these modules](https://github.com/hlissner/doom-emacs/blob/develop/docs/getting_started.org#modules):

   - `:lang (go +lsp)`
   - `:tools lsp`
   - `:editor snippets` (should be enabled by default)
2. Install `gopls` through your OS' package manager (iirc it comes with Go 1.12+).
3. Run `~/.emacs.d/bin/doom sync` to ensure Doom is properly synchronized with these changes.

And you should be good to go. Here are some helpful (evil centric) keybinds you should know:

- <kbd>gd</kbd> `+lookup/definition` -> go to definition of the symbol at point
- <kbd>gD</kbd> `+lookup/references` -> jump to reference of the symbol at point
- <kbd>K</kbd> `+lookup/documentation` -> look up documentation of the symbol at point
- <kbd>SPC c a</kbd> `lsp-execute-code-action` -> executes an arbitrary code action (which should include auto-generate what you're asking for).
- <kbd>SPC m h d</kbd> `go-guru-describe`   -> Describe this
- <kbd>SPC m h v</kbd> `go-guru-freevars`   -> List free variables
- <kbd>SPC m h i</kbd> `go-guru-implements` -> Implements relations for package types
- <kbd>SPC m h p</kbd> `go-guru-peers`      -> List peers for channel
- <kbd>SPC m h P</kbd> `go-guru-pointsto`   -> What does this point to
- <kbd>SPC m h r</kbd> `go-guru-referrers`  -> List references to object
- <kbd>SPC m h c</kbd> `go-guru-callers`    -> Show callers of this function
- <kbd>SPC m h C</kbd> `go-guru-callees`    -> Show callees of this function
- <kbd>SPC m t t</kbd> `+go/test-rerun`     -> rerun last test
- <kbd>SPC m t a</kbd> `+go/test-all`       -> run all tests
- <kbd>SPC m t s</kbd> `+go/test-single`    -> run test at point
- <kbd>SPC m t n</kbd> `+go/test-nested`    -> run tests below

You'll find a more comprehensive list of keybinds [in the :lang go module](https://github.com/hlissner/doom-emacs/blob/develop/modules/lang/go/config.el#L26-L61) (Note that `SPC` is Doom's leader key, and `SPC m` is its localleader key. For non-evil users, these are `C-c` and `C-c l`, respectively).

The snippets module comes with [a snippets library](https://github.com/hlissner/doom-snippets). You can find our modest go snippets [here](https://github.com/hlissner/doom-snippets/tree/master/go-mode), and you can add your own to `~/.doom.d/snippets/go-mode/`.

I also suggest you [visit the `:lang go` readme](https://github.com/hlissner/doom-emacs/blob/develop/modules/lang/go/README.org). It needs updating, and I'm hardly a good resource on how much of it you need with gopls, but perhaps there are corner cases it can help cover.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your response. Could you please give me some hints for the "Navigation" part  in my question?  Or what common packages/tools are required to do similar things in other language.

Comment: I'm currently trying to get this same thing set up. It looks like I have everything installed, but the `SPC-m` localleader doesn't seem to exist. Am I using the wrong localleader? When I type out `SPC-m`, I get `SPC-m is undefined`.

Comment: UPDATE (in case someone else has the same problem): in `config.el`, I set `(setq doom-localleader-key "m")`. `SPC-m` still doesn't work. But I can do `m t s`, so problem solved.